# Does it make sense to import functions explicitly when exported by default and used a objectorientated interface?

Tags: perl, import, module, export

Does it make sense - when loading a module - to import needed functions explicitly when the module does export these functions by default and when it is used a object-orientated interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is subjective, but yes, it often makes sense. Default imports are more convenient, but explicit imports are somewhat safer, in that you're less likely to accidentally import something without knowing about it.

> […] and when it is used a object-orientated interface?

If a module *only* has an object-oriented interface, then it shouldn't export very much by default (since method calls don't benefit from the method names having been imported). If a module offers *both* an object-oriented interface *and* a procedural one, and you're only using the object-oriented interface, then it's very likely to be a good idea to specify your imports explicitly, since you'll need very few imports (or none at all). This depends, of course, on whether the module exports any of its procedural function-names by default.

Answer (score 2):

By explicitly declaring the functions that you want to import, even if they are exported by default, also stops the module from importing the other functions you may not be using it would have exported by default.